# Unable to test WebSocket client in PHP

Tags: php, phpunit, ratchet

I am using [Prawl](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl/) as a Websocket client in PHP. I want to test whether message is being fetched or not. When I run code I get 0 assertions error because message is received asynchronously. Below is code

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../class/SCBridge.php';

class SCBridgeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $_log = null;
    protected $_config = null;
    protected function setUp() {
        $this->_config = parse_ini_file('../config/config.ini',true);

        \Logger::configure(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../config/config_daemon.xml');
        $this->_log = Logger::getLogger('LOGGER_X');
        print "Setup run \n";
    }
    public function testCanConnect()
    {

        \Ratchet\Client\connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8080')->then(function($conn) {
            $conn->on('message', function($msg) use ($conn) {
                print $msg."\n"; //it can print this
                $this->assertEquals('true',true); // did not execute
                $this->assertEquals("Hello World",$msg); // did not execute
                $conn->close();
            });

            $conn->send('Hello World!');
        }, function ($e) {
            echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        });
    }
}
```

It outputs:

> Time: 1.42 seconds, Memory: 4.50Mb
>
> OK (1 test, 0 assertions)